# UITableView with Additional Header "Layer"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I wasn't sure how to word my title, but what I'm trying to do is break down a UITableView with multiple "layers" of headers. Essentially, instead of a 2D array (sections * rows) I'd like to break it down in a 3D manner (sections * sub-sections * rows) with different types of `UIView`s for the headers in sections vs sub-sections.

Essentially, this sort of format, but in a UITableView:

[image: Table Organization]
etc.

Is there a way to do this relatively easily, or will I need to go through setting up logic to detect what type of section I'm dealing with in `viewForHeader`, `rowsInSection`, `heightForHeader`, etc. and try to handle accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, there are options, some off the top of my head:

- multiple tableViews
- tableView within collectionView
- pseudo-header with logic

the last option i mean to say if (['sub-section' isEqualTo: 1]), then append Section header view to Sub-section header, however, your sub-section would in actuality be the section

it should not be so bad to do with collectionView or the aforementioned.

Comment: Thanks- I like the idea of appending the Section header to the first sub-section. That way I only need to manage a single tableView.

Comment: Did discover a downside to this approach- the "Section" header view is only anchored to the top of the table when navigating the first sub-section.

Comment: You'll have to assign the TableView delegate for custom headers, or implement your own with UIView. Each section should be "stickied" to the top of it's respective section automagically

Comment: Right- I'm using my own `UIView` for the header, and it anchors to the top correctly. The issue is that when using the "append the Section header to the first Sub-section header" approach is that, well, the main section is only part of the first sub-section's header, so it's only anchored when the first sub-section is anchored. Scrolling down to sub-section 2 leaves the main Section's view behind with sub-section 1.